# How to get the zxing for my app only in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing as a library to implement the QRCode scanner. This is launched by clicking on a button. But when I click on the button, it gives a list of all the applications which has zxing installed and I have to choose my own application's scanner.

Is there a way where I can specify to simply start the scanner without any choice being given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android")` to restrict the Intent to only match the Barcode Scanner package. This is done for you if you use the `IntentIntegrator` code in the project.

Comment: Hey Sean, I used IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MyActivity.this) but that is still giving me the choices of applications to use from. And yes, I did the implementation of onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) as it is given in the documentation of IntentIntgrator class

Comment: That's bad, because it means some other app has declared itself in our namespace (`com.google.zxing.client.android`). That's not your app, is it? Please don't use our package name because it causes *exactly this problem* for all our users.

Comment: No it is not my app...it is some other free android qrcode reader I downloaded.

Comment: I would complain to them, since it is making it impossible to integrate directly with the app you want to. What's the app?

Comment: Barcode Scanner owns this namespace, so of course responds to this Intent. I find that My Diet Diary also intercepts Intents to scan product codes. This is wrong, and you should complain to them to change it. There's no good reason they are intruding on another app's namespace.